# How do I create an alpha only bitmap context

Tags: ios, core-graphics, alpha, cgbitmapcontextcreate

Apple tech note [QA1037](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1037/_index.html) says "To create an alpha-only bitmap context simply pass NULL for the colorspace parameter."

However, I am not sure what to pass for the `bitmapInfo` parameter.

I was trying something like this, with kCGImageAlphaOnly:

```
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height, 8, scaledSize.width, NULL, kCGImageAlphaOnly);
```

But this gives me an warning about the enum being wrong. What should I put there instead?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The docs clearly state you can use values from the `CGImageAlphaInfo` even though the parameter is defined as needed a value from the `CGBitmapInfo` enum.

One solution would be to cast the value:

```
(CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaOnly
```

That will make the compiler happy.