# Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'CGImageAlphaInfo'

Tags: xcode, resize, uiimage, ios7

ive updated my project to IOS 7 and now i am getting this error when resizing an image once added/taken within the app here is my code

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)anImage width:(int)width height:(int)height
{

CGImageRef imageRef = [anImage CGImage];

CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
    alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;


CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), 4 * width, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), alphaInfo);

CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(ref);

return result;  
}
```

The error im getting is this

Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'CGImageAlphaInfo' (aka 'enum CGImageAlphaInfo') to different enumeration type 'CGBitmapInfo' (aka 'enum CGBitmapInfo')

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create an alpha only bitmap context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245787/how-do-i-create-an-alpha-only-bitmap-context)

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921703/implicit-conversion-from-enumeration-type-enum-cgimagealphainfo-to-different-e

Answer (score 1):

I have inserted **(CGBitmapInfo)**  before your variable alphaInfo.
Hope it solves your problem

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)anImage width:(int)width height:(int)height
{

CGImageRef imageRef = [anImage CGImage];

CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
    alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;


CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), 4 * width, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), (CGBitmapInfo)alphaInfo);

CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(ref);

return result;  
}
```